# Applozic Meteor integration

Tags: meteor-blaze, applozic

I cant able to run applozic-web fullview ui with meteor (1.4.2.6).
(https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin)

I've put src folder under /client/compatiblity folder. I'm newbie and i'm not sure how exactly use jquery plugins. Here is my html code is on http://pastebin.com/6canHZnK
respective js code is nearly empty.

I got ui screen with no functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any javascript error? you can see that in chrome developer tools -> console

Comment: My error logs is on http://pastebin.com/tgepeTad  . I dont know if it is related but Jquery version is jquery@1.11.10

Comment: can you open the web page and then save it as html and share that

Comment: HTML version is this but i'm not sure if it helps http://pastebin.com/vNecS0Ew. This is the export of console->elements http://pastebin.com/iJE7ma7s